# Comparing vectors in assembly

Tags: assembly

I have two vectors; one of them (VectorA) is introduced by the user, and the other (VectorB) contains a bunch of single digit numbers. Both of them are char vectors. The idea is that the program has to compare one by one the numbers of VectorA to make sure they are valid numbers, by comparing them to the ones in VectorB, which contains all the valid numbers available.

If all the numbers in VectorA are contained in VectorB, the program returns 0. If any of the numbers of VectorA is not present in VectorB, the program returns 1 instead. The return register is `EAX`.

Here's the code, I hope it's not too messy, but bear with me (also please excuse if I use wrong terminology since English is not my native language)...

---

```
    MOV edi, 5     ;VectorA is a 5 digit vector.

character_1:
    mov rcx, 10    ;VectorB is a 10 digit vector.

character_2:
    mov eax, [ebx+edi-1]       ;ebx contains the address of VectorA    
    cmp eax, [VectorB+rcx-1]    
    je found_it    
    loop character_2  

    mov eax, 1    
    jmp end_comp   
found_it:

    dec edi    
    cmp edi, 0    
    jne character_1

    mov eax, 0
end_comp:
```

---

First off, I know I probably shouldn't have used `EAX` as an index, but after trying with a whole bunch of other registries `EAX` was the only one that didn't make `YASM` freak out.

The problem is... It doesn't seem to work. The first verification loop works fine. If the last number of VectorA is a 9, it actually goes to the `found_it` tag and does what it has to do. However, no matter what the second number is, it never finds it on VectorB.

For debugging purposes, I added a `mov esi, [VectorB+rcx-1]` line right above the main `CMP` line where the two values are compared. I found out that the first time they are compared, `ESI` has the correct value. However, the second time the program goes through that instruction, `ESI` returns a 14648 value, which of course doesn't correspond to the contents of `EAX` in the next line.

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Whoops, I think I found the problem...
It seems the eax register is not meant for single-byte contents (the vectors have characters in them, which are byte-sized). I changed the lines...

```
mov eax, [ebx+edi-1]    
cmp eax, [VectorB+rcx-1]
```

...to...

```
mov al, [ebx+edi-1]    
cmp al, [VectorB+rcx-1]
```

And now it seems to work.
It seems eax was actually reading 4 bytes of the vector instead of 1.

Thanks anyways. :)

Answer (score 0):

Two obvious errors to start with

mov edi,5

and yet the first cmp has edi-1, so it starts at 4

====

mov rcx,10

and yet the first cmp has rcx-1, so it starts at 9

====

cmp edi, 0

jne character_1

mov rcx,10

character_1 resets the loop at 10 in the middle of an edi loop, is that ok?

====

Don't know what rcx is, I assume its ecx being used to loop character_2

mov rcx, 10  I presume is ten digital, not 16 binary

Once you sort all the guffy little details out it will rock but the devil is in the detail with these teeny routines

=========

"If the last number of VectorA is a 9, it actually goes to the found_it tag"

This is because the jump always resets rcx at 10, then has a cmp rcx-1 (so rcx=9)

so it goes 10 9 cmp 10 9 cmp 10 9 cmp instead of 10 cmp 9 cmp 8 cmp 7 6 etc

Comment: rcx and edi have the -1 in the cmp lines because they need to go through positions 0-9 and 0-4 of their respective vectors, instead of 1-10 and 1-5.
The way this is supposed to work: Edi is searching through all the digits in Vector1. For each one, rcx goes through Vector2 and starts comparing the numbers. The moment they find a coincidence, edi is decreased to the next number in Vector1 and rcx is reset to 10 so it can start comparing again. If a single rcx loop goes through without jumping to the found_it tag, it means the valor in edi is not in Vector2, therefore the whole thing stops.

Answer (score 0):

character_1:

mov rcx, 10    ;VectorB is a 10 digit vector.

character_2:

```
mov eax, [ebx+edi-1]       ;ebx contains the address of VectorA    

cmp eax, [VectorB+rcx-1]    

je found_it
```

## loop character_2

What will happen here if there is no match?

edi will be edi-1 forever

You still need to find a way to deprecate edi

edi=edi-1 kinda thing

You do

dec edi

if there is a match, but keep edi the same if there is no match

Comment: That's because if there's no match, then there's no point in searching anymore. The moment it finds a single digit in VectorA that's not part of VectorB, the whole VectorA becomes invalid, and the program exits returning 1 via eax.